# Uniquely identifying clustered ellipses which are about the same shape, but different sizes

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on an image of parasite eggs. I need to identify as many eggs as I can individually, I've managed to decent borders around them using the watershed algorithm, but I want to look at the oval egg as a whole, rather than just the yolk part which is generally what the watershed algorithm picks out. I have tried ellipse detection but it only gets the water bubbles (the round black bits with a white dot in the middle) which I actually want to ignore (but am planning to implement later).

What would be the best method to achieve this, I've looked into image mapping but it only returns the best match, I've also considered shape recognition but it apparently isn't implemented in OpenCV.

Here is what my result I get using the watershed algorithm:
http://imgur.com/7ptyIOL

And here is an idea of what I'm wanting to get: http://imgur.com/XPLUixa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right I've been hacking away at it today and this is the solution I've found. I threshold the image, and then I find the contours. After I have found the contours I will draw an ellipse around each of them if it passes a little check function I have made. This currently works quite well, but I will need to improve my method of thresholding the image before I can expect any real progress.

This code generates the contours and draws them

```
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in contours:
  #will give an error if there are less than 5 points
  if len(c) > 4:
    elip = cv2.fitEllipse(c)
    if check_ellipse(elip):                                                    
      cv2.ellipse(img, elip, (255, 0, 0))
```

This is the function used to check the correctness

```
def check_ellipse(ellipse):
  h = ellipse[1][0]
  w = ellipse[1][1]
  #make sure it's not too large, or too circular
  if abs(h-w) < 2 or h > 30 or w > 30:
    return False                                                                              
  return True
```

Later on I may change this so it first gets rid off all of the ellipses which don't pass the test, that way I can have a list of their coordinates which is what I really need if I want to progress with this program.